# leaflet open specific marker popup on button click

Tags: javascript, popup, leaflet

I'm trying to open a specific marker's popup on some event(say, button click). In order to do so I add an id property to a marker and store all markers in an array. But for some reason, the id property of a marker inside of an array is undefined when I try to access it.

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
var markers = [];
var marker = L.marker([51.5, -0.09]);
marker["id"]="0";
marker.bindPopup('!');
marker.addTo(map);
markers.push(marker);

openPopupById("0");

function openPopupById(id) {
    for(var marker in markers) {
        alert("Marker's id " + marker["id"] + " target id " + id );
        if (marker["id"] === id) {
            //marker.openPopup();
            alert("opening " + id);
        }
    }
    alert(id);
}
```

UPDATE
Ok, I found the solution: I should replace `for` with

```
for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; ++i)
```

And access markers as `markers[i]["id"]`

But can someone explain me why the first version doesn't work?

Comment: May be that would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/how-to-do-for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

I think your mistake is the use of push (in markers.push(marker))

To store the markers, you should use

```
markers["id"] = marker;
```

You can open your popup like that

```
markers["id"].openPopup();
```

For the markers to know their id

```
marker.id = "id";
```

Comment: Yes, that is probably a better solution if I don't want marker to know it's id for some other reason. I'll think about it. But can you tell, why the first solution in my question didn't work?

Comment: use marker.id (not marker["id"]) as marker is not an array. I have updated the answer

Comment: If this is the case, why my updated solution worked? I just don't understand the difference between them.